# How to transform a string into a keyword in Common Lisp?

Tags: string, type-conversion, common-lisp, keyword-argument

I have this list:

```lisp
((":name" "postalCode" ":type" "tel")
 (":name" "firstName" ":value" "Pedro " ":type" "text")
 (":name" "lastName" ":value" "Moyses Delfino" ":type" "text")
 (":name" "email" ":value" "p.delfino01@gmail.com" ":type" "text")
 (":name" "password" ":value" "senha-minha" ":type" "password")
 (":name" "confirmPassword" ":value" "senha-minha" ":type" "password")
 (":name" "cpf" ":value" "117.349.446-41" ":type" "tel")
 (":name" "rg" ":value" "MG1727039" ":type" "tel")
 (":name" "dateOfBirth" ":value" "07/05/1993" ":type" "tel")
 (":value" "female" ":type" "checkbox") (":value" "male" ":type" "checkbox")
 (":value" "31" ":type" "tel") (":value" "98765-4332" ":type" "tel")
 (":value" "31" ":type" "tel") (":value" "3456-7890" ":type" "tel")
 (":value" "on" ":type" "checkbox") (":value" "on" ":type" "checkbox")
 (":value" "on" ":type" "checkbox") (":value" "on" ":type" "checkbox")
 (":name" "login" ":type" "text") (":name" "password" ":type" "password")
 (":name" "login" ":type" "text") (":name" "login" ":type" "text")
 (":name" "password" ":type" "password"))
```

Semantically, there are keywords before strings such as `:name` and `:type`. Due to the data parsing before this, they keywords are camouflaged. I would like to convert them to be real keywords. So, the first element in the list would change from:

```
(":name" "postalCode" ":type" "tel")
```

To:

```
(:name "postalCode" :type "tel")
```

I think there are *some* ways to do this. Which solution would be an elegant way to solve it?

Thanks.

Comment: Use `read-from-string`

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to use `read-from-string` and have the result in lower case?

Comment: If the keyword were in lower case it would print as `:|type|`. Is that really what you want?

Comment: If you type `(:name "postalCode" :type "tel")` you get uppercase keywords. Using `read-from-string` does the same thing.

Comment: I am not sure if these `| |` are going to affect further functions... Not sure. I guess being upper is "ugly" but harmless, correct?

Comment: Anyway, you can use `readtable-case` to control how the reader converts case.

Comment: It depends on how you plan on using it. If you write `(if (eql keyword :name) ...)` it won't work if you put the keyword in lower case, because `:name` is actually read as upper case.

Comment: OK, thank you very much! Another thing, I tried what you said:  "If you type `(:name "postalCode" :type "tel")` you get uppercase keywords". I tried to see what you said in the REPL, but `CL-USER> (:name "postalCode" :type "tel")` throws an error.

Comment: Quote it to type into the REPL `'(:name "postalCode" :type "tel")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CL-USER 26 > (defun convert-string-to-keyword (string
                                               &key
                                               (upcase t)
                                               (max-string-length 100))
              (and (<= 2 (length string) max-string-length)
                   (char= (char string 0) #\:)
                   (let ((string1 (subseq string 1)))
                     (when upcase
                       (setf string1 (string-upcase string1)))
                     (values (intern string1 "KEYWORD")))))
CONVERT-STRING-TO-KEYWORD

CL-USER 27 > (convert-string-to-keyword ":foo")
:FOO

CL-USER 28 > (convert-string-to-keyword ":")
NIL

CL-USER 29 > (convert-string-to-keyword ":foo" :upcase nil)
:|foo|
```

converting a list of key-value-lists:

```
(defun convert-key-value-lists (lists)
  (loop for list in lists
        collect (loop for (key value) on list by #'cddr
                      collect (convert-string-to-keyword key)
                      collect value)))
```

Answer (score 3):

I am going to make few assumptions about the data:

- The data is always in the form (key value key value ...).
- The data is always well formed.

Lets do it step by step.

```lisp
(defvar *data* '((":name" "postalCode" ":type" "tel")
 (":name" "firstName" ":value" "Pedro " ":type" "text")
 (":name" "lastName" ":value" "Moyses Delfino" ":type" "text")
 (":name" "email" ":value" "p.delfino01@gmail.com" ":type" "text")
 (":name" "password" ":value" "senha-minha" ":type" "password")
 (":name" "confirmPassword" ":value" "senha-minha" ":type" "password")
 (":name" "cpf" ":value" "117.349.446-41" ":type" "tel")
 (":name" "rg" ":value" "MG1727039" ":type" "tel")
 (":name" "dateOfBirth" ":value" "07/05/1993" ":type" "tel")
 (":value" "female" ":type" "checkbox") (":value" "male" ":type" "checkbox")
 (":value" "31" ":type" "tel") (":value" "98765-4332" ":type" "tel")
 (":value" "31" ":type" "tel") (":value" "3456-7890" ":type" "tel")
 (":value" "on" ":type" "checkbox") (":value" "on" ":type" "checkbox")
 (":value" "on" ":type" "checkbox") (":value" "on" ":type" "checkbox")
 (":name" "login" ":type" "text") (":name" "password" ":type" "password")
 (":name" "login" ":type" "text") (":name" "login" ":type" "text")
 (":name" "password" ":type" "password")))
```

First step is to convert the stringified keywords to proper keywords.

```lisp
(defun parse-keyword (string)
  (intern (string-upcase (string-left-trim ":" string)) :keyword))

CL-USER> (parse-keyword ":name")
:NAME
:EXTERNAL
CL-USER>
```

That is good enough. I don't need to check if the string begins with ':' because I assumed from the structure of the data, all odd values (first third ...) are keywords, and I don't need to care about even values.

Second step is to parse a single list of values.

```lisp
(defun process-a-list-of-kv (kv-list)
  (let ((result nil))
    (alexandria:doplist (k v kv-list)
      (push (parse-keyword k) result)
      (push v result))
    (nreverse result)))

CL-USER> (process-a-list-of-kv (first *data*))
(:NAME "postalCode" :TYPE "tel")
CL-USER>
```

It uses `alexandria:doplist` to iterate on two values (k and v) at the same time. I convert k to keyword and do nothing with v. if you are not going to use Alexandria, you could do it with loop as:

```lisp
(defun process-a-list-of-kv (kv-list)
  (let ((result nil))
    (loop for k in kv-list by 'cddr
          for v-list = (cdr kv-list) then (cddr v-list)
          for v = (first v-list) then (first v-list)
          do (push (parse-keyword k) result)
             (push v result))
    (nreverse result)))
```

and finally to process the original list:

```lisp
CL-USER> (mapcar 'process-a-list-of-kv *data*)
((:NAME "postalCode" :TYPE "tel")
 (:NAME "firstName" :VALUE "Pedro " :TYPE "text")
 (:NAME "lastName" :VALUE "Moyses Delfino" :TYPE "text")
 (:NAME "email" :VALUE "p.delfino01@gmail.com" :TYPE "text")
 (:NAME "password" :VALUE "senha-minha" :TYPE "password")
 (:NAME "confirmPassword" :VALUE "senha-minha" :TYPE "password")
 (:NAME "cpf" :VALUE "117.349.446-41" :TYPE "tel")
 (:NAME "rg" :VALUE "MG1727039" :TYPE "tel")
 (:NAME "dateOfBirth" :VALUE "07/05/1993" :TYPE "tel")
 (:VALUE "female" :TYPE "checkbox") (:VALUE "male" :TYPE "checkbox")
 (:VALUE "31" :TYPE "tel") (:VALUE "98765-4332" :TYPE "tel")
 (:VALUE "31" :TYPE "tel") (:VALUE "3456-7890" :TYPE "tel")
 (:VALUE "on" :TYPE "checkbox") (:VALUE "on" :TYPE "checkbox")
 (:VALUE "on" :TYPE "checkbox") (:VALUE "on" :TYPE "checkbox")
 (:NAME "login" :TYPE "text") (:NAME "password" :TYPE "password")
 (:NAME "login" :TYPE "text") (:NAME "login" :TYPE "text")
 (:NAME "password" :TYPE "password"))
CL-USER>
```

Answer (score 0):

Following @Barmar's advice, I have built:

```lisp
(defun convert-keyword (string-list)
  (cond ((null string-list) nil)
        ((equal (subseq (first string-list) 0 1) ":")
           (cons (read-from-string (first string-list))
                 (convert-keyword (rest string-list))))
        (t (cons (first string-list)
                 (convert-keyword (rest string-list))))))
```

Which returns:

```lisp
((:TYPE "tel" :NAME "postalCode" :VALUE)
 (:TYPE "text" :NAME "firstName" :VALUE "Pedro ")
 (:TYPE "text" :NAME "lastName" :VALUE "Moyses Delfino")
 (:TYPE "text" :NAME "email" :VALUE "p.delfino01@gmail.com")
 (:TYPE "password" :NAME "password" :VALUE "senha-minha")
 (:TYPE "password" :NAME "confirmPassword" :VALUE "senha-minha")
 (:TYPE "tel" :NAME "cpf" :VALUE "117.349.446-41")
 (:TYPE "tel" :NAME "rg" :VALUE "MG1727039")
 (:TYPE "tel" :NAME "dateOfBirth" :VALUE "07/05/1993")
 (:TYPE "checkbox" :NAME :VALUE "female")
 (:TYPE "checkbox" :NAME :VALUE "male") (:TYPE "tel" :NAME :VALUE "31")
 (:TYPE "tel" :NAME :VALUE "98765-4332") (:TYPE "tel" :NAME :VALUE "31")
 (:TYPE "tel" :NAME :VALUE "3456-7890") (:TYPE "checkbox" :NAME :VALUE "on")
 (:TYPE "checkbox" :NAME :VALUE "on") (:TYPE "checkbox" :NAME :VALUE "on")
 (:TYPE "checkbox" :NAME :VALUE "on") (:TYPE "text" :NAME "login" :VALUE)
 (:TYPE "password" :NAME "password" :VALUE) (:TYPE "text" :NAME "login" :VALUE)
 (:TYPE "text" :NAME "login" :VALUE) (:TYPE "password" :NAME "password" :VALUE))
```

Comment: there are some issues: the function name does not match what it actually does. READ-FROM-STRING will execute code embedded into the string. Common Lisp has characters -> one can compare characters and can avoid SUBSEQ. The function may blow out the stack with large lists, depending on the implementation used.

Comment: Thanks! I am using SBCL, would that be the case of blowing ou the stack?  On the name issue, would `execute-keyword` be technically a better name? Or even `eval-keyword`?

Comment: Using READ-FROM-STRING opens up security problems, because it allows code execution. Either see \*read-eval\* or just use INTERN.

Comment: couldn't one just use READ-FROM-STRING and just ensure that it contains no lisp expressions but is just a simple keyword containing string - to avoid the security problem?