# Why getf does not work for these keywords in Common Lisp?

Tags: common-lisp, keyword

I can use `getf` to extract values inside a list:

```
CL-USER>(defvar regular-list-keys '(:name "pedro" :value "2985"))
REGULAR-LIST-KEYS

CL-USER> (getf regular-list-keys :name)
"Pedro"

CL-USER> (getf regular-list-keys :value)
"2985"
```

Ok. I was expecting the same to happen when dealing with `|:keywords|`:

```
CL-USER> (defvar odd-list-keys '(|:name| "jazoest" |:value| "2985" |:type| "hidden"))
ODD-LIST-KEYS
CL-USER> (getf odd-list-keys :name)
NIL
CL-USER> (getf odd-list-keys |:name|)
error
```

Why does this happen? And how can I solve this?

Obs.: I can change previous work which is returning data with `|:foo|` format if it is necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's two problems.

First, escaping a symbol prevents case folding. So with the pipes, you get lowercase symbols, rather than the default uppercase symbols (unless you've modified `(readtable-case *readtable)`).

Second, putting `:` inside the pipes makes it a literal character in the symbol name, not the keyword package prefix. So you're creating an ordinary symbol in the current package, not a keyword.

`:name` is a symbol named `"NAME"` in the `KEYWORD` package. `|:name|` is a symbol named `":name"` in the `CL-USER` package.

Symbols that aren't in the `KEYWORD` package don't automatically evaluate to themselves. So you need to quote `|:name|`. This will work:

```
(getf odd-list-keys '|:name|)
```

Comment: Maybe you want `:|name|` instead of `|:name|`.

Comment: I'm not sure why he wants any of this, rather than the usual `:name`

Comment: I am following the suggestion from this other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68597256/how-to-transform-a-string-into-a-keyword-in-common-lisp

Comment: And changing the input to be the suggested output on the other question. Your help was useful anyways to understand the symbol trick. Thanks.